# jquery tablesort wont show dialog, update cache, sort then close dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I am using the jquery plugin tablesort from http://mottie.github.com on my table. What is meant to happen is

- you click the header cell
- a jquery ui dialog shows saying loading
- the table cache updates using the update event as data changed via user input
- sort happens
- then the dialog is removed

The problem is the dialog is not opening always or wont close and if I open the dialog in the events sortStart and sortEnd then it opens and closes twice but it waits to open until the update event is complete.

If I use an alert it works better but thats not what I want, I need a dialog.

botton line is I need to use the update event and a dialog..... can yo please help.. my concept code is below.. thanks

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>
    <link href="css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom.min.js"></script>



    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function () {
            //add table sort
            $("#myTable").tablesorter();


            // bind to sort events begin
            $("#myTable").bind("sortBegin", function (e, table) {

                $('<div id="myDialog">loading</div>').dialog();

                $("#myTable").trigger("update"); // update table cache
                //alert('open');
            })

            $("#myTable").bind("updateComplete", function (e, table) {
                //alert("updateComplete")
            });

            $("#myTable").bind("sortStart", function (e, table) {
                //alert("sortStart")
            });

            $("#myTable").bind("sortEnd", function (e, table) {
                //alert("sortEnd")
                $('#myDialog').dialog("close");

            });



        });


    </script>




</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>


        <table id="myTable" class="tablesorter"> 
  <thead> 
    <tr> 
      <th>Last Name</th> 
      <th>First Name</th> 
      <th>Email</th> 
      <th>Due</th> 
      <th>Web Site</th> 
    </tr> 
  </thead> 
  <tbody> 

    <tr> 
      <td>Smith</td> 
      <td>John</td> 


         <td>jsmith@gmail.com</td> 
          <td>$50.00</td> 
          <td>http://www.jsmith.com</td> 
        </tr> 

<!-- this is here to simulate loads of extra rows -->
          <% For index = 1 To 100

                  Response.Write("<tr><td>Doe</td><td>Jason</td><td>jdoe@hotmail.com</td><td>$100.00</td><td>http://www.jdoe.com</td></tr> ")

              Next
              %>

        <tr> 
          <td>Conway</td> 
      <td>Tim</td> 
      <td>tconway@earthlink.net</td> 
      <td>$50.00</td> 
      <td>http://www.timconway.com</td> 
    </tr> 
  </tbody> 
</table>


    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nitpick: Using $("#myTable") over and over again is bad practice. Store it into a variable one time and use it as a reference. It will speed up your code since it is not creating a new jQuery object and selecting from the DOM each time, other option is to use chaining. Same idea.